# How do I make a code for saving the top 5 scores for this guess the number game?

Tags: python

```
from random import *

tries = 0

guessNum = randint(1,1000)

while True:

guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1-1000: "))
print("You have",29-tries,"tries left.")    
if guess >= guessNum+1:
    print("Too high")
    tries += 1
elif guess <= guessNum-1:
    print("Too low")
    tries += 1
if guess == guessNum:
    print("You got it right!!")
    tries += 1
    print("It took you",tries,"tries.")
    f = open("scoreBoard.txt","a")
    f.write("%-s,%-s\n" %(tries,guessNum))
    f.close()
    break
if tries == 30:
    print("You failed, the number was:",guessNum,".")
    break
```

I need help with putting it into a scoreboard that will update if there is new highscore. I know how to append the stuff to a txt file but how should I code it so that it only has the top five scores?

Comment: When someone answered your question you typically mark that question as correct. If it does not work it's best practice to ask more questions and explain your problem. We invest our own time here to help each other and basic recognition grows the platform to be more helpful as it encourages more cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

add your scores in a list called `numbers` then

```
numbers.append(yourNumber)
numbers.sort(reverse = True)
del numbers[5:]
```

then store the list `numbers`

Answer (score 1):

You first want to put the scores into memory. You can do that quite easily with a list.

```py
highscores = [0]*5
```

now when you get a new score you want to put it into the list at the correct position. Let's say the first item in the list is the lowest and the last one is the highest. Now we can write a function that will append the highscore to the list, sort it and then return the 5 highest scores.

```py
def place_highscores(score: int, highscore_list: list):

    size = len(highscore_list)
    highscore_list.append(score)
    highscore_list.sort()
    highscore_list = highscore_list[-size:]

    return highscore_list
```

Now you can simply place new highscores into the scoreboard by calling this function:

```py
>>>highscores = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
>>>highscores = place_highscores(4, highscores)
>>>print(highscores)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

Once you want to save the data you can write it to a file. You can either do that directly in your own format, you could use pickle, or json, which I prefer because the extension comes with python and is very easy to use:

```
import json

dict = {
    "highscores": highscores
}

with open("path/to/file", w) as file:
    json.dump(dict, file, indent=4)
```

Here's some documentation for json: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dump-in-python/